# display the HTML Reporter status widget in the bottom right corner

Tags: meteor-velocity

I am writing a mobile app and my upper right corner contains a function button. I need to move the status widget to the lower right button in order to access all the functionality on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was to add following CSS to my header:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #velocity-status-widget {
     top: initial;
     bottom: 0px;
     transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(45deg)
  }
</style>
```

the key part is the `top: initial` in order to reset the value